# Will adding column to replication db have influence on source db?

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, transactional-replication

If I add column to a replication database, will this column also be added to source database? I'm using transactional replication.

PS I don't want it to be added to source, I just want to make sure it won't make changes on original db :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't. Just make sure your column is nullable.